# django:: run manage.py from within django code

Tags: django, manage.py

How can I run the manage.py script from withing django code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Instead you call [`django.core.management.call_command()`](http://michaeltrier.com/2007/11/21/using-call_command).